# Retrieving selected item from listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How do i retrieve values from selected item in listbox.

I have a databound listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EventsListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         SelectedValuePath="idevents" 
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate2}" 
         />
```

Which uses this datatemplate to populate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,5,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <DockPanel TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=eventname, FallbackValue=Manchester}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                </DockPanel>


                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=realchannelname, FallbackValue=Channel}" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=datetime, FallbackValue=datetime}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How would i get 'eventname' value and set it as a string to a label here;

```
Private Sub EventsListBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles EventsListBox.SelectionChanged

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use SelectedItem property!

Comment: Ok, i have figured it out.

        `MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(EventsListBox.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("eventname"))`
 does the trick

Answer (score 0):

In general, I try to do things through binding because they will automatically update.

In Code Behind you can gain access to the value of the item via the SelectedValue property.

```
String value = EventsListBox.SelectedValue;
```

A better way of doing this is to have a binding update a property. This way everything always will update with bindings

```
<ListBox x:Name="EventsListBox"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEventName} >

</ListBox>
```

You should note that the SelectedEventName is a property on the viewmodel that the listbox is bound to.